# Right/Length Not Working

Tags: excel

OK so trying to use the formula below

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-(RIGHT(A1)=","))
```

On a cell that contains the formula:

```
=IF($I10>0,CONCATENATE($H10," - ",$I10,", ",IF($K10>0,CONCATENATE($J10," - ",$K10,", ",IF($M10>0,CONCATENATE($L10," - ",$M10),"")),"")),"")
```

Which translates to

```
Tiffany - 5, Ben L - 4, Cat - 4
```

Now if I setup a simple test with a cell with "1," in it, code works fine, it removes the comma. Will not work what so ever if there happens to be a "," at the end of it, which can happen if a particular person comes back with 0 as their result.

Comment: formulas != code, also removed the vba tag as it was not appropriate in this case. It works with your test cell, but not with *any* other value ending in a comma?

Comment: The formula itself seems needlessly obscure. `=IF(RIGHT(A1) = ",",LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1),A1)` spells out the logic more clearly.

Comment: Can you use the [tag:textjoin] worksheet function instead of the CONCATENATE? Might solve some problems right off the bat by negating the need to check for a trailing comma.

Comment: I'd agree with @JohnColeman that's a weird form of function you're using, I had to break it apart to make sure what it was doing. I'd also recommend using his version which is far more standard implementation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your concatenation formula is appending a `", "` (comma + space), so the last character in your cell value is not a comma, but a space. This is why it works in your test case `"1,"` but not in actual cases.

Use the `TRIM` function in conjunction with your formula to ignore trailing whitespace:

```
=LEFT(TRIM(A2),LEN(TRIM(A2))-(RIGHT(TRIM(A2))=","))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow that's why you don't work on this stuff well after bed time, didn't even cross my mind, thanks!